# Regular expression match formatted text in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have formatted text like this:

```
Record
name=aaa
age=16
info=blabla bla

Record
name=bbb
age=15
info=foo bar foo bar
```

Would like to convert it into arrays with regular expression in PHP. So far I've tried:

```
preg_match_all("/Record.*\n(?m:^(.+)=(.+)$)+/",$text,$matches);
```

But it only catches `"Record name=aaa"` and `"Record name=bbb"`
Wondering why the `+` does not work in this case. So how should I form my pattern here?

Comment: What was *?m:* for? Is it multiline expression without matching?

Comment: According to this http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html It should be multi-line modifier for grouped patterns. I use it so the `^` and `$` can match a line of text

Comment: You need `/s` modifier instead of `/m`

Comment: Another vote against regex. This is something that could be done with a simple lexer.

Comment: Yeah it explodes my head :) Needs more explanation about why I should use single-line modifier here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [will do it](http://codepad.viper-7.com/92Y4Rx).

```
$data = array_values(array_map(
    function($e){
        preg_match_all('/(.*?)=([^\r\n]*)/', $e, $m); 
        return array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);
    }, 
    array_filter(explode("Record", $text))
));
```

First it splits the whole data by `Record` as delimiter using [explode](http://php.net/explode) and [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter). Then for each of the chunk it extracts the key-value pair using [preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all) and constructs an associative array (by [array_combine](http://php.net/array_combine)).

Comment: Thanks! It do works perfectly, even with the arrays assembled :)

Answer (score 2):

You have not matched the newlines after the first. Move the `\n` inside the `(?m:...)` section

Comment: Hi @Kolink, but the `^` inside (?m:) should match beginning of new lines?

Comment: So I replaced `^` with `\n`, the whole strings are matched, but output array only takes `info`s and their content as groups. In another word, only the last of `(.+)=(.+)` pattern is matched as groups :(

Comment: @XunYang, yes, `^` does match the position "Start of the line" but not a character. It matches the position after a `\n`, but not the `\n` itself.

Comment: @XunYang this happens because the capture group does not store all the matched content. It has storage only to store the last one.

Comment: Alright! Seems like that's how regex works, I wouldn't be able to solve my problem purely with regex then. Thanks for the answer still :)